# Why this promise never gets resolved?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, nonblocking

I'm testing a code that adds promises to a queue and they should be processed in a non-blocking way. I have a code that works as expected but other that doesn't and I don't understand why.

Code that does not work as expected:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const promiseQueue = require('promise-queue');

let currentQueueSize = 0;
const maxQueueSize = 5;

// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
const queue = new promiseQueue(maxQueueSize, maxQueueSize);

const requestData = () => {
  currentQueueSize++;
  queue
    .add(() => axios.get('https://catfact.ninja/fact'))
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result.data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      currentQueueSize--;
    });
};

const run = async () => {
  while (true) {
    if (currentQueueSize <= maxQueueSize) {
      console.log('current queue size ', currentQueueSize);
      requestData();
    }
  }
};

run();
```

I was expecting that this would add things to the queue and when they are resolved the queue size would decrease and then I would be able to add more things to it. But in this scenario the `then` never gets executed on the `requestData` function.

However if I change the run code to this:

```
const run = async () => {
  while (true) {
    if (currentQueueSize <= maxQueueSize) {
      console.log('current queue size ', currentQueueSize);
      ingestData();
    } else {
      await new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
        const waiter = () =>
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (currentQueueSize <= maxQueueSize) {
              console.log(`Queue size ${currentQueueSize} now under  max queue size of ${maxQueueSize}, resuming...`);
              resolve(true);
            } else {
              console.log(`Waiting for queue size to reduce, current queue size ${currentQueueSize}`);
              waiter();
            }
          }, 1000);
        waiter();
      });
    }
  }
};
```

The `then, catch and finally` code is executed as expected and I can keep adding things to the queue when the promises are resolved. Why the first code doesn't work but the second does?

Comment: Don't maintain your own `currentQueueSize`, [a `Queue` has getter methods for that](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-queue#interface)!

Comment: What's the actual goal here? Do you really want to keep calling `requestData()` forever? As fast as possible?

Comment: No @Bergi the while(true) was just to make it simple. But basically what I'm trying is get a data from a source and send it to a destinary, the process would end when all data is processed from the source. But I'm more curious about why the first code doesn't work than anything

Comment: In that case, you should just write `for (const data of source) queue.add(() => send(data))`.

Answer (score 3):

`while (true)` is an infinite loop. You don't have an `await` in the loop body, so it never suspends. This is blocking the entire application, and prevents the promises from resolving (or at least their handlers from executing).

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, so why having an await on the loop body resolves the `requestData` functions? Given I'm not awating the requestData function this is not intuitive for me.

Comment: It's not the `await` that causes the promise to resolve. The promise does that by itself, when axios request finished. The problem with the infinite loop is simply that it causes the entire nodejs application to hang, so it never gets to do anything else but loop.

Comment: You'd have the same problem if you did `requestData(); while (true) { /* oops */ }; console.log('unreachable');`